# Что быстрее и практичнее межпроцессное взаимодействие или многопоточность?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Опишу что мне предстоит сделать.

Будет одно приложение которое будет каждую миллисекунду (или даже микросекунду) посылать данные. Данное оно будет передавать подпрограмме которая будет их использовать и отправлять назад первому приложению. Все операции будут происходить в пределах одного сервера (или ПК).
Собственно у меня встал вопрос как лучше с минимальной задержкой и в идеале без проблем потери памяти построить всю архитектуру этой задумки. Дело в том что программ пользователей этих данных может быть от одной до сотни или более, они должны функционировать максимально независимо друг от друга. причем одновременно может быть запущено несколько копий одной и той же программы пользователя данных

Писать планирую на С++ пока думаю писать под Линукс на возможно буду делать то же самое под виндовс. Пока есть пара задумок:
 1. Каждую программу пользователь данных создавать в виде dll, далее подгружать требуемую dll динамически и запускать класс который будет как раз в отдельном потоке выполнять свои действия. 
 2. Каждую программку делать в виде отдельного процесса, который через пайп будет получать данные передаваемые первой программой. По мимо пайпа думал над разделяемой памятью, однако я заранее не знаю сколько байт будет передано программой отправляющей данные.

Подскажите как бы Вы лучше организовали подобное взаимодействие ? Какой из вариантов пришедших ко мне в голову наиболее оптимален

---

Дополнение вопроса:

Производитель един для всех потребителей. Данные когда как, иногда несколько потребителей могут иметь одни и те же данные, иногда различные. Потребителей может быть сколько угодно. Потребители передают производителю данные в ответ по установленной форме (у каждого потребителя будет API на котором он будет общаться с производителем данных) Как раз и делема сделать ли потребителей как отдельные процессы, либо включить их в производителя как отдельные потоки.

Касательно данных - то формат данных будет един для всех потребителей но вот сами конкретные данные различны.

Comment: Не вполне ясно - есть один производитель данных, и много потребителей? Данные им поставляются одни и те же или каждому свои? Результаты обработки (разные?) потребители передают производителю? Потребители - отдельные процессы?

Comment: @MBo, последний твой вопрос как раз автор и задаёт ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy Он пишет о "программах", но хотелось бы уточнить, потому что в первом варианте неясно, кто dll использует.

Comment: Передача данных между процессами будет порядка на два (и как бы даже не на три) медленнее, чем передача данных между потоками одного процесса.

Comment: @MBo Производитель един для всех потребителей. Данные когда как, иногда несколько потребителей могут иметь одни и те же данные, иногда различные. Потрибителей может быть сколько угодно. Потребители передают производителю данные в ответ по установленной форме (у каждого потребителя будет API на котором он будет общаться с производителем данных) 
Как раз и делема сделать ли потребителей как отдельные процессы, либо включить их в производителя как отдельные потоки.

Comment: @MBo dll - это по сути и есть потребители. Производитель един а потребители будут создаваться как отдельные программы и что бы не влазить в код производителя данных постоянно - я думаю лучше будет сделать динамическую подгрузку dll в каждом из которых будет потребитель данных. ЛИБО делать потребителей данных как отдельные процессы.

Comment: @MBo Касательно данных -  то формат данных будет един для всех потребителей но вот сами конкретные данные различны.

Comment: @freim благодарю -за ответ. А что касательно моей идеи с dll - как это решение Вам ? Можно ли придумать получше ?

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar В вопрос это всё лучше добавить

Comment: Насчет подгрузки dll - так, собственно, и делается всегда. Других вариантов оформить загружаемые модули или плагины по-моему, вообще не просматривается.

Comment: процессы удобнее в плане изоляции друг от друга. Насчет обмена данными, если всё будет в рамках одного ПК, то посмотрите в сторону разделяемой памяти

Comment: @goldstar_labs, насчет разделяемой процессами памяти в голову приходит только memory-mapped files. Но это дело совсем небыстрое. Это только кажется, что там просто память разделяемая, на самом деле любая запись в эту память вызывает системное прерывание и далее операции ввода-вывода. Чтение, конечно, побыстрее чем из реального файла.

Comment: Тогда получается один вариант остается - dll модули. Благодарю всех за советы и помощь.

Comment: @freim, shm_open это вроде же совсем другое, чем memory mapped files

Comment: @goldstar_labs, это что-то из Линукса? Насчет этого ничего не скажу, а вот в Windows быстрого межпроцессного взаимодействия нет. Имеется в виду реально быстрого, вроде разделяемой памяти.

Comment: Чё-то я запутался. А почему данные для одних потребителей могут быть одни, а для других другие. Цитата: `когда как`. Сам потребитель будет сообщать производителю что ему производить ? ` Данные когда как, иногда несколько потребителей могут иметь одни и те же данные, иногда различные.` Или имеется в виду что формат одинаковый (текст допустим), а содержимое текста различное.  Но всё равно не понимаю, от чего зависеть будет разница в данных. Мне просто все это напомнило сервер и кучу клиентов.

Comment: @vegorov Передавать буду биржевые котировки в торговые роботы. формат котировок (структура) одинаков, но наполнение структуры - различное